# Is there a way to overcome the limitation of Solr

Tags: solr, nosql, rdbms

Is there a way to overcome the limitation of Solr

How to add an additional column to the collection that I have already created and have crores of data in it.

Comment: Please read [ask]. This is "too broad".

Comment: I have modified as you suggested. Can you now help me to get solution

Comment: This does not make any sense at all. You're comparing a range of technologies (RDBMs) against a single product. Please ask specific questions and make sure you've at least performed rudimentary research about the subject and how it affects the technologies first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new field to an existing schema, you can use the [Solr Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html):

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name":"sell_by",
     "type":"pdate",
     "stored":true }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema
```

The `type` parameter corresponds to the field type you want the new field to have.

If you're [using the old schema.xml format](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/defining-fields.html#defining-fields), you can add the field type in the XML there:

```
<field name="sell_by" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

You'll have to reload the configuration for the collection after changing it. If you're using Zookeeper (i.e. you're manually uploading your configuration to Zookeeper), you can [use `zkCli.sh` and `downconfig` and `upconfig`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/command-line-utilities.html) to download and upload the configuration set.

After adding the field, you'll have to reindex the documents that should contain the field by submitting them to Solr again, so that the content is added to the field as expected.

Comment: What about the values? Do I need to reload the complete data and reindex?

Comment: Yes, there is no way for Solr to magically make values appear that haven't been stored before. Even changing the definition of an existing field requires a reindex of existing data.